# Visual Studio Bundled Node Js vs standard alone

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-2015

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 and it comes with nodejs and npm now. Prior to installing Visual Studio i had installed a 64 bit Nodejs and this is up to date.

When I am trying to add gulp-less dependency to package.json file fails. Having a look at the Bower/NPM outputs I do see an Warning

```
npm WARN engine hawk@3.1.0: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.32"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.31","npm":"1.4.9"})
```

I suspect the issues is related to visual-studio being a 32 bit process it load a different version of Node and for unknown release ignores the 64 bit node js. This happens despite the fact I have $(path) varible before "$(DevEnvDir)\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WEB TOOLS\External" in External Web Tools.

So question is how do I update the Visual Studio version of Node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay got my solution.

1- Removed NPM and node from system -> path

2- Open command prompt with Administrator priviledge and navigate to visual studio install directory

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External
```

3- run `npm install -g npm`

that fixes the problem, also remember to restart visual studio afterwards.